# Spark sqlContext UDF acting on Sets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to define a function that works within Spark's DataFrame which takes scala sets as input and outputs an integer. I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 20 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 20.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 473, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Set
```

Here is a simple code that gives the crux of the issue:

```
// generate sample data
case class Dummy( x:Array[Integer] )
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  Dummy(Array(1,2,3)),
  Dummy(Array(10,20,30,40))
))

// define the UDF
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def setSize(A:Set[Integer]):Integer = {
  A.size
}
// For some reason I couldn't get it to work without this valued function
val sizeWrap: (Set[Integer] => Integer) = setSize(_)
val sizeUDF = udf(sizeWrap)

// this produces the error
df.withColumn("colSize", sizeUDF('x)).show
```

What am I missing here? How can I get this to work? I know I can do this by casting to RDD but I don't want to go back and forth between RDD and DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Seq`:

```
val sizeUDF = udf((x: Seq) =>  setSize(x.toSet))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I also managed to generalize to 2 sets as input (which was my original need)